# Wrapfig and multicol -- how to avoid wrapping text?

Tags: multicol, wrapfigure

I'm writing a report in two-column format using multicol

I'm placing some figures in the text using wrapfig

It works fine, when the figure is e.g. 50% of the column width

[image: Wrapping 50% of column width ... just fine and dandy!]

However, if I try to make the figure fill the entire column, I get text overhanging into the next column ... like this:

[image]

You will notice there is text super-impositioned to the right of the figure in the right-hand side column.

I realise there is a similar problem described elsewhere in these fora in relation to figure wrapping onto the next page and the (simple) solution there is to either move the figure away from the page break and/or change the position from r or l to R or L.

However ... that is not the issue here. No matter where or how I place the wrapfig, the following text is place next to the figure. It is as if wrap figure wont allow text *not* to wrap around the image.

So why don't I just drop wrapfig and simply use \includegraphics ... because I need the caption

Here is a minimal working example ... I don't have an image of a duck, sorry :-)

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}                       % Allow for switching between 1 and 2 columns
\usepackage{wrapfig}                        % To wrap text around small figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

Et af højdepunkterne i løbet af 2013 har været afslutningen af den første undersøgelsesrunde af de mere end 1000 patienter, som indgår i Rygcenter Syddanmarks kohorte til ’\emph{Tidlig diagnostik af Spondylartropati}’, som ligger til grund for Bodil Arnbaks PhD-afhandling, som blev forsvaret i 2014. 

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{gull.png}
\end{wrapfigure}

Projektet er et rigtig godt eksempel på hvordan kliniske data fra patienter, klinikere og MR-skanninger kan integreres i SpineData og anvendes til at besvare komplicerede forskningsspørgsmål. 2013 blev også året hvor patientspørgeskemaerne blev oversat til yderligere otte sprog. Spørgeskemaet har tidligere været tilgængelige på dansk og engelsk men kan nu også læses på tysk, arabisk, serbo-kroatisk, somali, tamil, vietnamesisk, tyrkisk og farsi. Dette betyder, at patienter kan indtaste deres helbredsoplysninger i spørgeskemaet på det sprog, som de kender bedst. Databasen ’oversætter’ selv svarene, så klinikerne ser svarene på dansk.

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't wrap it and use something like the `capt-of` or `caption` package?

Comment: While that is definitely a possible work-around (and I might just end up doing that) ... a _work-through_ which solves the problem using wrapfig would be better..

Comment: But you don't want to wrap the figure with text so `wrapfig` is not really appropriate here, is it? That is, that environment is specifically intended to wrap text around the figure and you specifically want it not to try to do that. So you are trying to tighten a screw with a hammer. It is not really a workaround to suggest you use a screwdriver in that case, although obviously if you bang the screw hard enough, it will penetrate eventually (albeit with results you may not have wished for).

Comment: a simple experiment will show that `wrapfig` with a figure that is as wide as the text will work no better on a one-column page -- it simply positions the minimum-width "overflow" lines against the left margin, overprinting the figure.  this isn't mentioned in the documentation, but i think a suggestion to the author of `wrapfig` that a warning about over-wide figures would be useful might be in order.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying and your analogy with the hammer and screwdriver :-)

Comment: The point is though: I want a workable, generic solution throughout a very long report which will place figures appropriately in one or two column formats, whether the figure is smaller than the column width (in which case it should wrap text) of not (in which case it shouldn't). However, I think what you're saying is that wrapfig is not able to solve that issue for me ... hence the caption-packages

Comment: An ordinary figure environment  and an ordinary `\caption` are relevant in the case of a column-wide image.

Comment: @Bernard But there are complications with single column floats in a `multicols` environment so I thought it might be easier to just insert the graphic and add the caption.

Comment: "It is as if wrap figure wont allow text not to wrap around the image." Not just "as if", but exactly that! Take the "wrap" from "wrapfigure" and you have "figure".

Answer (score 4):

Would need tweaking:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}                       % Allow for switching between 1 and 2 columns
\usepackage{wrapfig}                        % To wrap text around small figures
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\newcommand\myfigure[5]{%
  \ifdim#2>.8\linewidth
    {%
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=#3]{#4}%
      \captionof{figure}{#5}%
    }%
  \else
  \begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{#2}
    \includegraphics[width=#3]{#4}
    \caption{#5}
  \end{wrapfigure}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

Et af højdepunkterne i løbet af 2013 har været afslutningen af den første undersøgelsesrunde af de mere end 1000 patienter, som indgår i Rygcenter Syddanmarks kohorte til ’\emph{Tidlig diagnostik af Spondylartropati}’, som ligger til grund for Bodil Arnbaks PhD-afhandling, som blev forsvaret i 2014.

\myfigure{L}{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{example-image-a}{abc}

Projektet er et rigtig godt eksempel på hvordan kliniske data fra patienter, klinikere og MR-skanninger kan integreres i SpineData og anvendes til at besvare komplicerede forskningsspørgsmål. 2013 blev også året hvor patientspørgeskemaerne blev oversat til yderligere otte sprog. Spørgeskemaet har tidligere været tilgængelige på dansk og engelsk men kan nu også læses på tysk, arabisk, serbo-kroatisk, somali, tamil, vietnamesisk, tyrkisk og farsi. Dette betyder, at patienter kan indtaste deres helbredsoplysninger i spørgeskemaet på det sprog, som de kender bedst. Databasen ’oversætter’ selv svarene, så klinikerne ser svarene på dansk.

\kant[1]

\myfigure{L}{.5\linewidth}{\linewidth}{example-image-b}{def}

\kant[2]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: custom figure environment]